# Communication Active Directory users with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

I installed VM player in my machine and installed windows 2008 standard core inside. Also via command prompt added users and groups for a particular user as below,
creating user

```
dsadd user "cn=username,cn=users,dc=myname,dc=ca" -pwd password -disabled no
creating group
dsadd group "cn=groupname,cn=users,dc=myname,dc=ca"
Also added user to the existing group as below,
dsmod group "cn=groupname,cn=users,dc=myname,dc=ca" -addmbr "cn=username,cn=users,dc=myname,dc=ca"
```

Now i connect this users via my asp.net application in my local machine as below,
Web.config settings

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

script for authentication

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string adPath = "LDAP://domainaddress:389/DC=somename,DC=m"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
      LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
      try
      {


        if(true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), false);

            string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();

         //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
         bool isCookiePersistent = chkPersist.Checked;
         FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
           txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);
---------
-------
}
```

where i am getting exception in  string groups = adAuth.GetGroups(); as below
"Error authenticating. Error getting groups. The username is incorrect or bad password. "

Please let me know if i am doing some mistakes or please let me know how i find groups of assciated user.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Did you take LdapAuthentication class from msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx)? Could you show us the code of this class (if it is not too long)?